# Closed question punctuation formatting is inconsistent

Tags: bug, close-reasons, grammatical-correction

This is the most irrelevant bug, but here you go:

---

[image]

[image]

With these close reasons, the period after the word "**Closed**" is bold.

---

[image]

[image]

With these close reasons, the period is not bold. This is inconsistent.

Comment: Some [freehand red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/284827) might be useful to aid a lazy reader. :)

Comment: In before *Feature Request*: Allow drawing freehand red circles when pasting images into the question editor.

Comment: I agree that this is a most irrelevant bug, but I heartily approve of the pedantry to point it out. :-) This arose from the community-specific reasons having been edited by a CM and doing what was sensible with respect to bolding of sentences, without realizing that the network-wide close reasons had different formatting.